# start gnu screen with existing running program

Tags: gnu-screen

Say I forget to run screen at the beginning of login, I've started up a program like emacs, have many files open, now I want to attach this to a session of screen.  Is there any way to do this?  Or do I have to exit emacs, run screen, then run emacs again, opening up my work from the beginning?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: thanks for the answers.  it looks like this isn't entirely possible, at least not in a simple common way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This post from ServerFault might be useful: https://serverfault.com/questions/24425/can-i-nohup-screen-an-already-started-process

Comment: from what I can understand, this will remove the job from the current shell.  is there a way to attach this into a running instance of screen?

Comment: Sorry, not sure. You could try this, which seems to do some type of wacky process demarshaling/marshaling: http://cryopid.berlios.de/

Answer (score 1):

[reptyr](https://github.com/nelhage/reptyr) works if you're on linux

Answer (score -1):

I don't believe this is possible - your emacs session is a child process of your shell, and I believe that a secure OS is pretty strict about making changes to the process tree from outside the process.